# couchdb import / export with php script

Tags: php, couchdb

I found these scripts to export / import a couchdb:
[zebooka/couchdb-dump](https://github.com/zebooka/couchdb-dump)

I'm at a loss as to where to start with this? The usage says to run each script with the -h flag, but I"m not sure what this means?

Can anyone post an example of how to use these scripts?

Comment: Why use scripts? Why not just copy files manually or use replication?

Comment: -h is just for help. For example try: 
/my/bin/couchdb-dump.php -H localhost -p 5984 -d test > dump.json

Answer (score 0):

Just to have a copy of the data on another server that didn't have couchdb installed at the time.  For anyone looking to do this, here is the solution that worked for me:

```
<?php
// *** PUT YOUR CONNECTION TO COUCH HERE, try using: https://github.com/dready92/PHP-on-Couch

$client->limit(9999999999999);
$client->include_docs(TRUE);
$all_docs = $client->getAllDocs();
$filename = date('Ymdhis').'.json';

// *** BE SURE to include $path variable for the location of the file
$path = '';
$destination = $path . $filename;
$file = fopen($destination, "w+");
fputs($file,json_encode($all_docs));
fclose($file);
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($destination.'.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
$zip->addFile($destination);
$zip->close();
unlink($destination);?>
```